# How to ensure centroids of the clusters in k means algorithm doesn't switch everytime?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
date                       mse                                                  
2018-02-11                 14.34
2018-02-12                 7.24
2018-02-13                 244.5
2018-02-14                 3.5
2018-02-16                 12.67
2018-02-21                 45.66
2018-02-22                 15.33
2018-02-24                 98.44
2018-02-26                 23.55
2018-02-27                 45.12
2018-02-28                 78.44
2018-03-01                 34.11
2018-03-05                 23.33
2018-03-06                 127.45
...                        ...   
...                        ...
```

Now I try to apply **k means** to the `mse` values to get **2** `clusters` which gives me **2** `centroids` one for each.Now I am given a `mse` value and I need to find for which of the two `centroids` is nearer to the given `mse` value.I do something like this

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd

centroid_list = []
given_mse = 7.382409087
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=["date"])
kmeans.fit_predict(df[['mse']])
centroid_list.append(kmeans.cluster_centers_.ravel())
#print(centroids_list)  # array([  153.27996598, 19810.6925875 ]
for i in centroids_list:
t1 = abs(given_mse - i[0])
t2 = abs(given_mse - i[1])
if t1 < t2:
   result.append("label 1")
   else:
   result.append("label 2")
print(result)  # ['label1']
```

Now as you can see I get two `centroid` values `153.27996598` and `19810.6925875` assigned to each cluster.

The problem is it keeps switching the values often **[(x,y) or (y,x)]** when you run the program because of which I get the end result as either `label1` or at times `label2`.

Any idea how this can be fixed.Is there any sckit-learn technique to prevent this switching?

Comment: You could save the model and reload it rather than retraining.

Comment: @ncfirth I am sorry but I am not quite sure I understand.Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Create a separate script where you train the model and save it, example can be seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html). Then every time you use your model just load the saved one rather than retraining.

Comment: Use `random_state` param in KMeans

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks!It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Vivek Kumar, I needed to pass an additional parameter `random_state` while setting the k means.The value for `random_state` can be any integer.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=1)
```